# Frontend Developer Interview Coding Questions: a not defined and b is defined?

Tags: javascript

I got this question from [Frontend Developer Interview Coding Questions](https://github.com/h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions/blob/master/src/questions/coding-questions.md). Why the snippet below prints what it prints? I originally thought **it would throw a ReferenceError "b is not defined"** (because it looks like "we're about to assign a notdefined variable `b` to an intended defined variable `a`) but then it turns out "b is defined, a is not defined, and there's no Errors"? What's `var a = b = 3;` is called in javascript?

```js
(function(){
  var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

Comment: because `b` is not defined with `var` so it is global

Comment: @epascarello true, thank you. and if I use `use strict;` before those statements then it would deliver me the result as I originally expected!

Comment: And if there's no `= 3` go after, it will throw the error as I expected as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` only applies to `a` and not `b`. Therefore since `b` is not defined with `var` and is assigned a value, it becomes global.

If you rewrote the function how it is working, you can clearly see that `b` has no `var`

```js
(function(){
  var a;
  b = 3;
  a = b;
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

Comment: true! and it (undeclared becomes global) seems to be in nonstrict mode only? I don't even quite sure what's "strict mode" but I've heard of it!

Answer (score 1):

Because `var a = b = 3;` means `var a = window.b = 3;`
You are accesing b from window.